# OAuth - Google API unsupported_grant_type

Tags: php, curl, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I was already checking other threads with the same error and still couldn't fix it.

So here is my PHP code:

```
$data = [
        "client_id" => "id-here",
        "client_secret" => "secret-here",
        "refresh_token" => "refresh-token-here",
        "grant_type" => "refresh_token"
    ];
    $ch = curl_init( 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    dd($result);
```

As you can see I do have the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" included, yet I still get a response:

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

I hope that someone will be able to help.
Any tips, links, or code-snippets will do!
Thank you!

Comment: why arent you using the google api php client library?

Comment: I wouldn't want to include the whole PHP client lib, that I wouldn't need, just to send one get request in the end. That is why. But I think that I'd need to get that OAuth access token anyway somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=[TOKEN]&grant_type=refresh_token
```

The call is a http POST call and the data is a single string with options separated by an & sign.

You are sending the post data as an array.

Comment: So I should send this URL as a string in a POST request? (the $data variable in my code)

Comment: Like this:
$data = "client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=[TOKEN]&grant_type=refresh_token";

to the endpoint "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" instead of "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" that I'm using currently?

Comment: Always check the discovery document on any authorization server for the most up to date endpoints https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration